# How to run a java swing application with Docker because docker run command throws headless exception

Tags: java, docker, swing, dockerfile, docker-java

[image]

When I try to run the java swing image getting the "Headless Exception error"

DockerFile:

FROM openjdk:8

COPY requiredlibararies requiredlibraries

COPY myjar.jar myjar.jar
CMD ["java", "-Djava.awt.headless=true", "-jar", "myjar.jar"]

Comment: You need an X11 server running on the host and connected to the docker instance.

Comment: Thanks, I have installed the vcxsrv in my machine and used docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=${ipaddress} imagname /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container has to interact with the Mouse Keyboard and display of the your host machine to execute the GUI. Installed X11 server on the host machine and then communicated the container with the x11 server of my host machine.

1. Installed vcxsrv-64.1.20.8.1.installer
2. Started the Xlaunch
3. docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=${ipaddress of hostmachine} image/bin/bash

Comment: Note that X11 security is an afterthought, and if you can do this, you have it most likely turned it off.  Be absolutely certain that vcxsrv is not listening on a port exposed to others (configure your firewall and/or vcxsrv) or anyone can point to your machineand do nasty stuff.